# Elasticsearch - How to create an enrich policy using Elasticsearch-PHP Client without getting a not found error for an endpoint that clearly exists?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an enrich policy using the Elasticsearch PHP client like so:

```
    $params['name'] = "product-policy";

    $params['match'] = [
        'match' => [
            'indices' => 'products',
            'match_field' => 'isbn',
            'enrich_fields' => ['title']
        ]
    ];

    $this->elasticsearch->putPolicy($params);
```

The Endpoint `putPolicy` is clearly defined. Can find it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/Elasticsearch_Namespaces_EnrichNamespace.html#Elasticsearch_Namespaces_EnrichNamespace) and [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/aa641709ee8e19dcf71a8f45b7d686d9ffbe4c75/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/Enrich/PutPolicy.php)

Yet I keep getting this error: `Namespace [putPolicy] not found`

I'm also not totally sure how to update Elasticsearch-PHP Client to the latest version or how to find the current version install and which one is the latest for that matter. I have put this in composer.json `"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.7"` and run `composer update` which gave me `Updating elasticsearch/elasticsearch (v7.11.0 => v7.13.1)` while for `localhost:9200` I get:

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.0",
}
```

Any lead in the right direction with this issue would help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I should have accessed the desired Endpoint through the appropriate Namespace. In this case `enrich`: `$this->elasticsearch->enrich()->putPolicy($params);`